# C++ 64bit - Operation was attempted on object that is not a SOCKET

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I am new to socket programming and I was trying to ping a machine using socket programming. My code is compiled as a 64 bit platform.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
SOCKET    rawSocket;
struct    sockaddr_in saDest;
struct timeval Timeout;
fd_set readfds;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;
DWORD  dwRetVal;

rawSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

dwRetVal = getaddrinfo(pstrHost, NULL, &hints, &result);

saDest.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(result->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
saDest.sin_family = AF_INET;
saDest.sin_port = 0;

FD_ZERO(&readfds);
FD_SET(rawSocket, &readfds);

Timeout.tv_sec = 5;
Timeout.tv_usec = 0;

select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &Timeout);
```

As soon as I execute `select` call it returns with error: "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket". And error code `select() error: 10038`

Any ideas on what could have been wrong?

`UPDATE 1`: I have just tried `connect` before making `select` call like below

```
dwRetValue = connect(rawSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & saDest, sizeof(saDest));
```

and this call returning 0.

Comment: Why don't you check the return values for the functions you're calling?  For example, `socket()`, `getaddrinfo`, ...

Comment: I did. `socket()` returns a socket number (every time different number), and `getaddrinfo` is returning 0 every time. Actually I have error checks on my actual code. I just posted socket calls I am making. Sorry for the trouble if need I can post in detail with error checks too.

Comment: Where is s (the first argument to FD_SET) defined?

Comment: It was my bad copying please excuse. It is rawSocket.

Comment: Now remove the assignments to fd_count and fd_array[0].  FD_SET should take care of that for you.